# C++ Mapping strings to enums - string compare vs. map - performance optimization

Tags: c++, string, dictionary, enums

in my code I have to map input strings to enum values. This mapping is used quite often and according to a performance analysis it is a bottleneck.
Actually I compare the input string to all possible string values (if/then) an return the right enum value.

There are about 50 different values to compare.

Example:

```
enum properties_keys {
PROP_EXPANSION,
PROP_DIGITS,
PROP_INVALID,
//others...};
```

Compare-function:

```
properties_keys convertPropString(std::string input)
{
   if (input.compare("prop.expansion") == 0)
      return PROP_EXPANSION;
   if (input.compare("prop.digits") == 0)
      return PROP_DIGITS;
   //others...
   return PROP_INVALID;
}
```

Alternative: Using a map

Example:

```
properties_keys convertPropString(std::string input) {
    static std::unordered_map<std::string, properties_keys> const propStrings{
        { "prop.expansion", PROP_EXPANSION},
        { "prop.digits", PROP_DIGITS},
        //...
    };

    auto it = propStrings.find(input);
    if (it != propStrings.end()) {
        return it->second;
    }
    else { return PROP_INVALID; }
}
```

**QUESTIONS**:

- Are there any findings as to whether the two variants are significantly different in terms of performance? If so, which option is better?
- Are there better (faster) ways to solve the task?
- If you use the variant with the map, would it be better to define the map outside of the function? Or to put it another way: is it a performance problem because the map is first "built" with each function call?

Thanks to alle the experts out there.

Comment: `std::map::find()` has guaranteed O(ld N) while your `if` cascade has O(N). Even faster than `std::map::find()` is `std::unordered_map::find()`. It can result in O(1) with a reasonable hash function. (I assume that the `std::hash(const std::string&)` shouldn't be that bad but you may test this for your specific input.)

Comment: _is it a performance problem because the map is first "built" with each function call?_ Making your `std::unordered_map<std::string, properties_keys>` `static` means it is initialized only once (probably at the very first call of the function). `static` variables have a life-time from (at latest) first access until end of process - regardless whether they are declared inside or outside of function scopes.

Comment: If there's a performance bottleneck due to string compares, you might want to consider rethinking your design. You don't want those in your hot path.

Comment: just write performance test using google-benchamar, build in release mode and do measurements. Guessing which implementation is faster is not so easy as you can think and quite often there are unexpected results.

Comment: @Scheff: According to your first comment: Since I actually use an unordered map (see example), this should be the best variant to use?

Comment: Actually, you already tested an unordered_map and made it `static`. (I noticed.) So, what  is your question? There might be edge cases where a simple for-loop is searching faster on a contiguous array than a super-clever `std::unordered_map()` with hashing. (This really might happen due to cache-locality which is enabled/forced by contiguous storage and an unordered map cannot profit from this - AFAIK.) However, nobody else than you can find it out. Benchmark both algorithms for "typical" data and see what happens. ;-)

Comment: My last lesson, I had myself: I replaced `std::map` by `std::unordered_map` to find/eliminate duplicates in vertices (of which I have millions). In my test app. (with random input) the hashing outperformed the tree by significant 30 %. In the real application, the speed-up was not measurable anymore. The final leak of performance was caused by too many signals which resulted in too many updates of the GUI. Once, I had fixed _this_, I had a significant speed-up (regardless whether I used `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`) and user complaints were stopping. (One of my stories of old...) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Using `std::unordered_map<std::string, whatever>` means creating a string for each string literal, and a node for each map entry. That's a lot of thrashing through dynamic memory.

For a fixed set of things, I'd be inclined to hand-roll a map as a file-scoped array of elements, with each element consisting of a `const char*` and the corresponding value. The elements are hand-sorted by their names.

```
struct element {
    const char *name;
    properties_keys value;
};

element element_map[] = {
    { "prop.digits", PROP_DIGITS },
    { "prop.expansion", PROP_EXPANSION },
    ...
};
```

On the rare occasions when the enumerators change you have to manage the changes, keeping all of the elements in alphabetical order. If you're paranoid (and you should be), do something at startup to check that the order is correct.

Find an element with `std::binary_search` and an appropriate predicate.

Comment: Well, and to ensure that there is no mistake in coding/sorting the table "by hand", an assert with a lambda can be used which ensures that each element is less than its successor. (I'm one of these paranoids...)